# Prove that the set is measurable

Tags: measurable-functions, measurable-sets

Let $f_{n}(x)$ is a sequence of measurable functions on a bounded set $X$. Prove that the set $A = \{x\in X |f_{n}(x)\text{ is bounded}\}$ is  measurable. I have completely run out of ideas how this can be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $A=\bigcup_N \bigcap_{n} \{x: |f_n(x)| \leq N\}$